# Turn columns into array in BigQuery

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery

I would like to take a table such as this:

| key | col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "a" | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| "b" | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| "c" | 5 | 0 | 2 |
| "d" | 0 | 0 | 1 |

and turn it into this:

| key | col |
| --- | --- |
| "a" | `[0, 2, 3]` |
| "b" | `[1, 1, 3]` |
| "c" | `[5, 0, 2]` |
| "d" | `[0, 0, 1]` |

Basically, I want to merge columns into an array. In real life I have 60 columns, all containing integers. I'll take a struct too if that's easier. Basically, I don't want to have to deal with 60 column names dynamically.

I can't seem to find an answer for this anywhere, which baffles me - this must be a common use case? It must be late for me...

Comment: `select "key", [col1, col2, ... ] as col`

Answer (score 4):

How about using `array`?

```
select key, array[col1, col2, col3] as cols
from t;
```

Comment: Duh! I kept seeing "array" as a method, and examples where it is used as a method, which didn't work as it wants a SELECT as an argument - I've never used arrays in sql before :) Any hints as to how to do it dynamically? I have 60 columns that follow a numbered naming pattern...

Comment: @ElisabethGuegan . . . I would suggest that you ask a *new* question.  This answers the question asked here.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select key, 
  (
    select array_agg(cast(value as int64))
    from unnest(split(trim(format('%t', (select as struct * except(key) from unnest([t]))), '()'))) value
  ) col
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: did you have chance to try?